rxjs: tap multiple subjects at once
Given two subjects s1 and s2 with subscriptions,
const s1 = new Subject<number>();
const s2 = new Subject<number>();

s1.subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log("s1 emitted", value),
  complete: () => console.log("s1 completed"),
});

s2.subscribe({
  next: (value) => console.log("s2 emitted", value),
  complete: () => console.log("s2 completed"),
});

and given an observable, say of(1), I could pipe through s1 like so:
of(1).pipe(tap(s1)).subscribe();

which produces the output
s1 emitted 1
s1 completed

But what if you'd like to pipe through s1 AND s2 at once.
Of course I could do something like this:
of(1)
  .pipe(tap((x) => [s1, s2].forEach((s) => of(x).subscribe(s))))
  .subscribe();

which produces the output
s1 emitted 1
s1 completed
s2 emitted 1
s2 completed

But is there a better/shorter way? I tried merge and the lot, but nothing works.

Looks like you're trying to push into s1 and s2.
You might want to use the pull approach and define s1 and s2 as merges from the other stream.
const yourStream = of(1); // ...

const s1 = new Subject<number>().pipe(
  mergeWith(yourStreaam)
);

const s2 = new Subject<number>().pipe(
  mergeWith(yourStreaam)
);

Then you just push into yourStream and that will cascade to both s1 and s2.

Maybe you can create a utility function to combine multiple Observers into a single one.
function mergeObservers<T>(...obs: Observer<T>[]): Observer<T> {
  return {
    next: (v) => obs.forEach((ob) => ob.next(v)),
    error: (v) => obs.forEach((ob) => ob.error(v)),
    complete: () => obs.forEach((ob) => ob.complete()),
  };
}

const merged = mergeObservers(s1, s2);

of(1).pipe(tap(merged)).subscribe()

// s1 emitted 1
// s2 emitted 1
// s1 completed
// s2 completed

